# Change url font size

Tags: fontsize, url

In my document, I needed to change the url font size. I found this solution: `\renewcommand\UrlFont{\footnotesize}`.

It does the job, but this changes font size of all the urls. But I need to change the font size of some url and keep the rest normal. I have searched for possible solution but all solutions applies to the whole document.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Then redefine the command only locally, inside some brace group.

Comment: Try, for example, `{\large\url{www.google.com}}` or `{\footnotesize\url{www.google.com}}`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Such a simple solution and I missed that completely.